# Implementing chartjs online

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Hello how can i fix chartjs it run perfectly on my localhost but when i put it online it doesn't ?How can i fix this your help is much appreciated

The code run perfectly in the localhost but when uploaded online the bar doesnt appear or the chart doesnt work

Here is the code

```
            $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','evaluatordb');
            $query = $con->query("
            SELECT strand, COUNT(*) as total
            FROM rank
            GROUP BY strand;
            ");

        foreach($query as $data)
        {
            $strand[] = $data['strand'];
            $total[] = $data['total'];
        }
        <select onchange="location = this.value;">
        <option value="superadmin.php?q=12">Strand</option>
        <option value="superadmin.php?q=10">Gender</option>
        <option value="superadmin.php?q=11">Age</option>
        
       </select>

       <canvas id="myChart3"></canvas>
       </div>
    }
    

    <script>
        // === include 'setup' then 'config' above ===
        const labels = <?php echo json_encode($strand) ?>;
        const data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
            label: 'Strand',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($total) ?>,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)',
                'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.5)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5)',
                'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.5)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
                'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
                'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
                'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 2
            }]
        };

        const config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data,
            options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
            },
        };

        var myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart3'),
            config
        );
        </script>
```

I try changing the

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>`
but it also didn't work.

Comment: is the first line, for the  database connection, still correct it says `localhost`

Comment: Yes i changed it when i put it online but it didnt work.

Comment: Can you provide the rendered output from the online site? Since the the `php` code version seems to work (if it works on localhost). The problem can be, in the database output, the database connection, the php / server configuration or the, webserver configuration. To find the error, it would be good to know, how the rendered output looks like and if there are errors in the browser console, when you open the page on the live server.